# Which database fits better this model: I have a JSON tree, users can add comments for any key

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database, nosql

I have a web application in which we show a tree content to the user, like a JSON structured file. The user, through the web application can add comments for any key of the JSON. And the main functionality is to be able to chance the value for that key and to keep an history of changes.

When the user is done modifying the structure, he can publish its changes. The output then is the same JSON file but with the latest modifications for the values.

Which database engine fits better this application? We are currently using MySQL but have heard from other devs that NoSQL databases can be the solution here. Should we use MongoDB, CouchDB or any of those? How would you approach the database model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that choosing the database depending on your model is not the right approach. Choose your database on your availability/scalability/simplicity requirements and then figure out how to fit your model in the database you choose.